# Datatable-not able to export newly added rows to the CSV files using tabletools

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, datatable

I having a datatable to which I keep on appending rows based on some actions. Now I also have a csv export button to export the table as a CSV. This is how I am initializing the table

```
mytable = $("#serviceTable").dataTable({
"bPaginate": false, 
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
"sSwfPath": contextRoot+"/js/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
"aButtons": [
 {
 "sExtends":    "csv",
 "sButtonText": "Export To CSV",
 "sFileName": "Operations.csv"
 }
]
},
});
```

I have two rows initially in the table, and I keep on appending new rows using `fnOpen`.

Now when I export the table to CSV only the original two rows are getting exported not the latest contents of the table? what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your eventListener only grabs onto elements that were on the page when it was instantiated, You Need wait until you are ready to move it to CSV and then attach the Listener.